# Syntax Error Sql/PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make pagination in PHP using SQL, the pagination logic is not the problem or anything, the problem is that I am not getting my table and rows printed, I decided to echo the sql sentence and try it directly into the sql program, and it gives me a syntax error which I don't understand because it seems just as good as the examples I have seen.

The thing is that I don't get why is that error I'm getting and why is it wrong or why the LIMIT is not getting accepted.

This is the sql sentence I'm echoing, (seems pretty good to me):

[image: This is the sql sentence I'm echoing, (seems pretty good to me)]

This is the error I'm getting (and which I'm guessing is the problem why my table isnt printing):

[image]

Comment: mind posting some real code, rather than an image of? *grazie*

Comment: Looks like you try to use MySQL syntax in SQL-Server

Comment: lol, how dumb, thank you ! HAHAH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use SQL Server syntax, like:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM trArchivos_test WHERE idArticulo=1 AND idFraccion=1
```

Comment: yeah now I get that but now i need (and i dont know which is it) the equivalent of the offset